# Best way to calculate percentile for every single value from actual and very large sized daily data (time 36500 X lon 3600 X lat 1500)

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, statistics, python-xarray

I have NETCDF files consisting of actual measurements of different variables at the daily scale and in a 3D format (time, lat, lon). The data size is huge, it is for 150 years at 0.1 degree spatial resolution covering the whole world (10 variables X 25 ensembles X 54750 days X3600 longitude grids X 1500 latitude grids). Now, I am planning to go one by one for variables and ensembles. I want to calculate the percentile of every single data value and then write a netcdf replacing the value with it's corresponding percentile. So far I have tried different methods to do it and none of them actually worked.

Try 1:

```
xarrayelems = []
startdatestr = '1953-01-03'
enddatestr = '2014-12-31'
startdate = datetime.datetime.strptime(startdatestr, '%Y-%m-%d')
enddate = datetime.datetime.strptime(enddatestr, '%Y-%m-%d')
x =0
while startdate<=enddate:
    try:
        vv = xr.open_mfdataset(inpath)
        xx = vv.isel(ensemble=1).isel(time=0)['Evap_tavg']
        xarrayelems.append(xx)
        startdate = startdate + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    except:
        startdate = startdate + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
        continue
    
combined = xr.concat(xarrayelems, dim='time')

dates = pd.date_range(start='1/3/1953', end='12/31/2014')
print(dates)
combined['time'] = dates
combined['east_west'] = lon[:360]
combined['north_south'] = lat[:300]

quantiles = np.arange(0.01,1,0.01)
print(quantiles)
percentiles = combined.chunk(dict(time=len(combined.time))).quantile(q=quantiles, dim='time')

newds = xr.where(combined.notnull(), percentiles, combined)
```

Please note that I tested for smaller period and subset of data, the final newds had a wrong dimension consisting of 99 percentile values in place of a single value. So the output dimension was X days* 3600 lon*1500 lat*99 percentiles which was wrong.

Try 2:

```
def replace_with_percentile(value, percentiles):
    return np.interp(value, percentiles, np.arange(0, 101))

# Apply the function to each element of the original dataset
ds_percentiles = xr.apply_ufunc(
    replace_with_percentile, combined, percentiles,
    input_core_dims=[['time'], []],
    dask='allowed',
    output_dtypes=[float]
)
```

This time it showed a very weird error which I even could not understand. SO tried the third one:

Try 3:

```
from scipy import stats
percentiles =  stats.percentileofscore(combined, combined, kind='rank')
```

This one took a very long time and it ran ok. But the output is consisting only nan values in every single grid. I indeed have nan values but I was not sure how I could filter out nan values. But I have grids where I dont have any nan values but yet the output is nan values.

Try 4:

```
percentiles = np.empty_like(combined)
print("Starting . . .")
for i in range(combined.shape[1]):
    for j in range(combined.shape[2]):
        print(j)
        percentiles[:, i, j] = stats.percentileofscore(combined[:, i, j], combined[:, i, j], kind='rank')

# Create a new DataArray with percentiles
percentile_data = xr.DataArray(
    percentiles,
    dims=combined.dims,
    coords=combined.coords,
    name="percentile_temperature"
)

# Create a new dataset with only the percentile data
ds_percentile = xr.Dataset({"percentile_temperature": percentile_data})
```

First part of this code was running smoothly but it is extremely slow and I cannot finish one loop in a few minutes (I have 3600 loops to do). The lower panel where I used xarray.ufunc, this code is saying that I have a mismatch in the dimension and it did not ran.

Now my question is,

1. which approach is the most efficient to handle very large dataset? I am pretty open to use pandas, xarray or any other well known library to do it.
2. If it is stats.percentileofscore, how can I ignore nan values? Can I run it in xarray.ufunc?

Any help regarding it will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please make your code reproducible and minimal. We really do not need to know how you are looping through files to figure out what goes into the specific ensemble. Just shows show us a minimal version of what you are trying to and we can help

Comment: If you have multiple netCDF files, I suggest turning each of them to histogram-count file in some range. Basically, you have to in the beginning think about the accuracy of your data (for instance some variable in range X to Y, one can select dval = (Y-X)/100) and then convert the data into count values in ranges (X,X+dval),(X+dval,X+2*dval) in each file... Afterwards just sum these files and you have ended up with histogram, from which you can find the percentile values in each grid point. This is how I did it with large dataset.

Comment: @RobertWilson, thanks a lot for the comment. Updated based on your feedback. The main point here is how can I efficiently calculate percentile for each values and then replace with it for large dataset.